# How to clean-up HTTP::Async if still in use

Tags: perl, http, asynchronous, timeout

I am using Perl library [HTTP::Async](http://search.cpan.org/~evdb/HTTP-Async-0.10/lib/HTTP/Async.pm) as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTTP::Async;
use Time::HiRes;
...
my $async = HTTP::Async->new( ... );
my $request = HTTP::Request->new( GET => $url );
my $start = [Time::HiRes::gettimeofday()];
my $id = $async->add($request);
my $response = undef;
while (!$response) {
  $response = $async->wait_for_next_response(1);
  last if Time::HiRes::tv_interval($start) > TIME_OUT; 
}
...
```

When `while` loop timeout and script ends, I experience the the following error message:

```
HTTP::Async object destroyed but still in use at script.pl line 0
HTTP::Async INTERNAL ERROR: 'id_opts' not empty at script.pl line 0
```

What are my options? How can I "clean-up" HTTP::Async object if still in use, but not needed anymore?

Comment: Note that `remove` and `remove_all` have been added to HTTP::Async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you `remove` incomplete requests, but the module does not provide any interface to do so.

---

**Option 1**: Add removal functionality.

Add the following to your script:

```
BEGIN {
    require HTTP::Async;
    package HTTP::Async;

    if (!defined(&remove)) {
        *remove = sub {
            my ($self, $id) = @_;

            my $hashref = $self->{in_progress}{$id}
                or return undef;

            my $s = $hashref->{handle};
            $self->_io_select->remove($s);
            delete $self->{fileno_to_id}{ $s->fileno };
            delete $self->{in_progress}{$id};
            delete $self->{id_opts}{$id};

            return $hashref->{request};
        };
    }

    if (!defined(&remove_all)) {
        *remove_all = sub {
            my ($self) = @_;
            return map $self->remove($_), keys %{ $self->{in_progress} };
        };
    }
}
```

You should contact the author and see if he can add this feature. `$id` is the value returned by `add`.

---

**Option 2**: Silence all warnings from the destructor.

If you're ok with not servicing all the requests, there's no harm in silencing the warnings. You can do so as follows:

```
use Sub::ScopeFinalizer qw( scope_finalizer );

my $async = ...;
my $anchor = scope_finalizer {
    local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { };
    $async = undef;
};
...
```

Note that this will silence all warnings that occur during the object's destruction, so I don't like this as much.

Comment: @user1215106, It's safe. The warnings are meant to alert you that you asked for something to be done and it wasn't done.

Comment: @user1215106, Updated to add `$async->remove_all`.

Comment: @user1215106, Fixed and tested.

Comment: Do you have the lastest version (0.10)? Btw, it doesn't currently remove unsent and completed requests.

Comment: update to newest version did a trick... I don't know what exactly was problem in, but now it looks just fine... thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to code it yourself or wait for the module author, unsent is probably not an issue, and you can check for completed requests before calling `remove_all`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too hard to subclass HTTP::Async for a more general solution. I use this to be able to abort all pending requests:

```
package HTTP::Async::WithFlush;
use strict;
use warnings;    
use base 'HTTP::Async';
use Time::HiRes qw(time);

sub _flush_to_send {
  my $self = shift;
  for my $request (@{ $self->{to_send} }) {
    delete $self->{id_opts}->{$request->[1]};
  }
  $self->{to_send} = [];
}

sub _flush_in_progress {
  my $self = shift;
  # cause all transfers to time out
  for my $id (keys %{ $self->{in_progress} }) {
    $self->{in_progress}->{$id}->{finish_by} = time - 1;
  }
  $self->_process_in_progress;
}

sub _flush_to_return {
  my $self = shift;                                                                 
  while($self->_next_response(-1)) { }
}

sub flush_pending_requests {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->_flush_to_send;
  $self->_flush_in_progress;
  $self->_flush_to_return;
  return;
}

1;
```

This is (maybe) easier on using the module internals than the code by @ikegami.